# Python Web Scraping: scraping a page with loading page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm building a web scraping project using python with Beautiful Soup and requests module, the problem is the website that i want to scrape has a loading page(completely different from the home page) before  it redirect me to the home page. How can i wait until the page done loading then scrape  the data from the home page. I know Selenium can handle these type of website but the website must be launched with a web driver which i don't want in my project, that's why i use Beautiful Soup and requests module. Here's my code so far.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

source = requests.get(url).text
print(source)
```

I just started my project, so this is all the code i written so far. I'm open with changing the module for this.

Comment: Mind sharing the URL of that website?

Comment: it's a website to read manga(japanese comic) for free, here is the [link](https://w11.mangafreak.net/). If you open the website for the first time, it will show the loading page.

Comment: I think, i found a solution for this. I can use selenium headless which don't open the browser but can still scrape the data. I'll try it and give an update if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

For you who don't want the browser to be launched when using selenium, use this code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
print(driver.title)
```

I already put by chrome driver into my computer's enviroment variable path. If you don't put your web driver into the path, change the driver variable into this

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='your web driver path', options=options)
```

Knowing that selenium can handle website with loading pages, this should fix my problem